# birational equivalence and mirror CYs

Tags: mirror-symmetry, birational-geometry, reference-request

If a CY X is a mirror to Y then any CY Z which is birational to X is also a Mirror of Y. This is the motivation for the Kawamata's "moveable Kahler cone" which includes the Kahler cones of all the CYs birational to X. Can you suggest a proof of this statement OR is there some reference  where this has been proved.

One way to look at it is in terms of the Bondal/Orlov conjecture about the isomorphism of the derived categories for birational CYs and Bridgeland's proof for dimension $\leq 3$, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Two birational varieties are expected to be derived equivalent ONLY if thay are K-equivalent, that is for any $W$ which maps regularly to both $X$ and $Z$ one should have `$p^*K_X = q^*K_Z$`, where $p:W \to X$ and $q:W \to Z$ are the projections. I guess you should include the assumption of K-equivalence in your question.

Comment: @Sasha - Since X and Z are both CY, they are automatically K-equivalent. 

I saw a nice talk today on mirror symmetry that included an example of 2 CY3s which are derived equivalent but are *not* birational. They both have the same mirror. 

Comment: @Jim - this seems interesting, could you please say something about the examples or some related references.

Comment: This is the paper that has the derived equivalent non-birational CY3s:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608404